# Assign increasing integer values to a column in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

We have an application where we have some learning path and each learning path is associated with some courses. The association between learning path and courses is stored in a mysql table. Now we also want to store course position in learning path to course mapping, so I have added another column 'position' in the table and I want to backfill existing data in it by a query in such a way that each course is assigned a number starting from 1 in any random way(Number should start from 1 for every learning path). For example,

```
LP1|C1         LP1|C1|1
LP1|C2   ==>   LP1|C2|2
LP1|C3         LP1|C3|3
LP2|C1         LP2|C1|1
LP2|C5         LP2|C5|2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MysQL 8.0, you can just use `row_number()` for this:

```
select 
    learning_path, 
    course, 
    row_number() over(partition by learning_path order by course) position
from mytable
```

If you need an `update` query:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select 
        learning_path, 
        course, 
        row_number() over(partition by learning_path order by course) position
    from mytable
) t1 on t1.learning_path = t.learning_path and t1.course = t.course
set t.position = t1.position
```

In earlier versions, one option is:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select 
        learning_path, 
        course, 
        (select 1 + count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.learning_path = t.learning_path and t1.course < t.course) position
    from mytable t
) t1 on t1.learning_path = t.learning_path and t1.course = t.course
set t.position = t1.position
```

Comment: This assumes (not unreasonably) that numbers don't exceed 9

Comment: We are using version 5.7.12

Comment: @Strawberry: yes, otherwise OP would need to have courses like `'Cnn'`.

Comment: @ManishRichhariya: I added a query for earlier versions to my answer.

Comment: Yes, or just 'n'.